# Xamarin New Bindable Picker Control

Tags: c#, xamarin

https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/

Im pretty new to xamarin and c# 
Somehow it isnt working for me...

```
 public class RegistrationPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        List<string> _countries = new List<string>
{
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",

};
        public List<string> Countries => _countries;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;




    }
    public partial class RegistrationPage : ContentPage
    {
        RegistrationPageViewModel vm;

        public RegistrationPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = vm = new RegistrationPageViewModel();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }



    int countriesSelectedIndex;
            public int CountriesSelectedIndex
            {
                get
                {
                    return countriesSelectedIndex;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (countriesSelectedIndex != value)
                    {
                        countriesSelectedIndex = value;

                        // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CountriesSelectedIndex));
                        SelectedCountry = Countries[countriesSelectedIndex];
                    }
                }
            }

        public string SelectedCountry { get; private set; }
    }
```

Im getting an error:The name 'Countries' does not exist in the current context

What Im doing wrong? And does someone have an working example

Comment: Which specific line is throwing the error?  You have Countries defined as a public field in RegistrationPageViewModel, you cannot simply reference it from another class without having an instance of your VM available.  It's also unclear where the third section of code is located - is that part of your page, your VM, or another class entirely?

Comment: SelectedCountry = Countries[countriesSelectedIndex];

Comment: try using vm.Countries instead, since vm is an instance of your VM

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write it (use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) rather than bother with `INotifyPropertyChanged`):

```
public class Country
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public Country(string name) => Name = name;
        public static Country Afghanistan = new Country("Afghanistan");
        public static Country Albania = new Country("Albania");
        public static Country Algeria = new Country("Algeria");
        public static Country Andorra = new Country("Andorra");
        public static Country Angola = new Country("Angola");

        public static IList<Country> Countries = new List<Country> { Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Andorra, Andorra, Angola };
    }

    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class RegistrationPageViewModel
    {
        public Country SelectedCountry { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegistrationPage : ContentPage
    {
        public RegistrationPage()
        {
            var vm = new RegistrationPageViewModel();
            BindingContext = vm;
            var picker = new Picker();
            foreach (var country in Country.Countries) picker.Items.Add(country.Name);
            picker.SetBinding<RegistrationPageViewModel>(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, x => x.SelectedCountry, converter: new PickerItemsToTypeConverter<Country>(Country.Countries));
            Content = picker;
        }
    }

    public class PickerItemsToTypeConverter<T> : IValueConverter
    {
        private readonly IList<T> _pickerItemsList;

        public PickerItemsToTypeConverter(IList<T> pickerItemsList) => _pickerItemsList = pickerItemsList;

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var itemType = (T)value;
            return _pickerItemsList.IndexOf(itemType);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var selectedIndex = value as int?;
            if (selectedIndex == null) throw new Exception("No selection");
            return _pickerItemsList[selectedIndex.Value];
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to bind this to forms? I tryied like in the document, but Im just getting empty picker